# update local bundle file if a newer version is available remotly

Tags: ios, objective-c, load, bundle

Inside the app bundle I have a PDF file which is used as "User guide" or Manual.

```
-(void)loadManual
{
    UIWebView *webPDF = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    webPDF.delegate = self;
    webPDF.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    webPDF.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:webPDF];
    webPDF.center = self.view.center;
    webPDF.tag = 88;




    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"manual" ofType:@"pdf"];
    if (thePath) {
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [webPDF loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
        textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

**Question**: How can I **elegantly** check my server for a newer version of "manual.pdf" and if there is a newer version on the server, download and replace the local file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compute the md5 of the file (check this [article](http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/) for iOS details) on both sides and if the results are different download the new version from the server. For doing this you could download the file to the Documents folder or similar, and I recommend you to mark it as not to be included in the iTunes backups, this will save you sometime with the revision process

Comment: can you please elaborate on the revision process in relation to this question, thanks.

Comment: Apple recommend not including the resources that can be recreated in the iTunes backup, [this Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) explain how to exclude files from the backup